# Null when doing shuffling

Tags: java, shuffle

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            size = Integer.parseInt(sizeText.getText());
            if(size<=1){
                error = "Please key in size more than 1";
                errorMsg.setText(error);
            } else if(size>=5) {
                error = "Please key in size less than 5";
                errorMsg.setText(error);
            } else {

                //create Table 1
                int sizer = size + 1;
                JTable table1 = new JTable(sizer, sizer){
                    public boolean isCellEditable(int r, int c){
                        return false;
                    }
                };
                String[][] Object = new String[sizer][sizer];
                String[][] Object2 = new String[sizer][sizer];
                int i = 1;
                Object[0][0] = " ";
                for(int r = 1; r<sizer; r++){
                    String text1 = "Col " + r;
                    table1.setValueAt(text1, r, 0);
                    for(int c = 1; c<sizer; c++){
                        String text2 = "Row " + c;
                        table1.setValueAt(text2, 0, c); 
                    }//first loop
                }//second loop
                for(int r = 1; r<Object.length; r++){
                    for(int c = 1; c<Object.length; c++){
                        Object2[r][c] = String.valueOf(i);
                        i++;
                        System.out.print(Object2[r][c]);
                        table1.setValueAt(Object2[r][c], r, c);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

                for(int r = 1; r<Object2.length; r++){
                    for(int c = 1; c<Object2.length; c++){
                        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(size);
                        String temp = Object2[r][c];
                        System.out.println("1: "+temp+ "/" +Object2[r][c]);
                        Object2[r][c] = Object2[rnd][c];
                        System.out.println("2: "+Object2[r][c]+ "/" +Object2[rnd][c]);
                        Object2[rnd][c] = temp;     
                        System.out.println("3: "+Object2[rnd][c]+ "/" + temp);
                    }//first loop
                }//second loop

                for(int r = 1; r<Object.length; r++){
                    for(int c = 1; c<Object.length; c++){   
                        table1.setValueAt(Object2[r][c], r, c);
                        panel2.add(table1);

                    }//first loop
                }//second loop  

                start.setEnabled(false);
                start.setText("Good Luck!");
                errorMsg.setVisible(false);
            }}  
    });
```

the reason why i have the system print out is for me to check on the shuffling process. It turns out, for no apparent reasons theres null values in it. Ive been trying to figure it out. My JTable will have blank spaces

Answer (score 1):

After your initialization with

```
for(int r = 1; r<Object.length; r++){
    for(int c = 1; c<Object.length; c++){
        Object2[r][c] = String.valueOf(i);
        i++;
        System.out.print(Object2[r][c]);
        table1.setValueAt(Object2[r][c], r, c);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

the array has following content (fields with `.` are `null`)

```
       0  1  2  3  4
    0  .  .  .  .  .
    1  .  1  2  3  4 
    2  .  5  6  7  8
    3  .  9 10 11 12
    4  . 13 14 15 16
```

it's because arrays use a zero based index.

Later when you shuffle

```
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(size)
```

`rnd` has a value in the following range `0 <= rnd < size`. Which means the `null` values can be swapped with some string values.

Comment: I have figure it out! Thanks alot. You made it clear now.

Ive added

'if(rnd!=0){'